# Java - Why while(true){ inputStream.read(incomingData) } does not work?

Tags: java, while-loop, java-io

I want to ask simple question. Let's consider this psudo code:

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream(); 

byte[] incomingData = new byte[1024];   
int incomingDataLenght = 0;

while(true)  {        
   incomingDataLenght =is.read(incomingData,0,incomingData.length);   
}
```

does not working.

But if you get byte array inside to while loop like

```
int incomingDataLenght = 0;

while(true)  {     
    byte[] incomingData = new byte[1024];    
    incomingDataLenght =is.read(incomingData,0,incomingData.length);   
}
```

everything is working well. The problem that i dont understand, when i declare a byte array, actually i'm declaring pointer. And one tour of while loop, i 'm giving that pointer to read method and it is filling my array which started from my declared pointer and i should use this pointer with fresh data. But in reality that does not work.

Could some one explain why it is not working?

### **Edit**

Sorry for my unclear question. I'm reading media bytes from socket and storing inside `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<byte>` for some buffering time(that is producer). Then my consumer thread is starting.  As i quoeted at above, when i move my array initialitizion inside the while loop, my data is gettin clear and my consumer thread can process my data successfully.

I think my answer is secret from my question. Whenewer i store byte array inside the queue, I'm stroing the same pointer(which is byte[] incomingData's pointer). When i start reading from queue, i'm reading current time's data instead of buffered data.

If this consideration is true, is that the best way to initialize array every while cycle?

Comment: What happens when you run the first code? Not working is not a description of the problem you're facing.

Comment: why are you saying it doesn't work. please provide stacktrace

Comment: The second loop will only break when you throw an EOFException.  The first loop will never throw an EOFException and it will instead spin forever.

Comment: @PeterLawrey can you explain why?  Your assertion does not appear to have any obvious rationale - the only variant seems to be whether `incomingData` was redeclared inside the loop.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your code? Why are you forever reading data, but not using the data that you have read?

Comment: You code is invalid: `byte[1024] incomingData = new byte[1024];` should be `byte[] incomingData = new byte[1024];`. @Fildor also corrected an error in your code. Please make sure that the code in your question is valid and compiles.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt It is not my code, but thanks. I corrected it, too.

Comment: @Fildor please don't - it hides the problems that the author has, and the fact that he hasn't made a lot of effort in the question. you're not supposed to change the code in a question AFAIK.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt it was an obvious typo. But of course, you are right in 99,9% of cases. The fact that he has described the behaviour told me he had it (syntactically) correct and running.

Comment: @Fildor The problems with typos like this is that they shouldn't happen - the code showing the problem should be copy&pasted directly, so that you can be sure that the problem exists with the real code and not whatever has been transcribed here.

Comment: @Alnitak Mea culpa ;)

Comment: @user1252105 - I'm guessing that "doesn't work" means that you get garbage data when you reuse the array. But your second example doesn't work either: you ignore the return value of `read()`, so you don't know how much data you're actually getting.

Comment: @Alnitak I miss read the code.  It is more likely that the problem is timing sensitive and creating a new byte[] each time, which is expensive, slows down the reader just enough that the problem is not seen.

Comment: okey i edited question and mentioned code is psudo-code

Answer (score 0):

although you didn't say what exactly happens with the first way, but there is an obvious difference between these two snippets :
in the second code 'incomingData' gets initialized every cycle!

Comment: it is an obvious difference, but it does not on the face of it explain the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Both examples will not compile with the error at

```
incomingDataLenght =is.read(incomingData,0,incomingData.lenght);
```

Should be

```
incomingDataLenght =is.read(incomingData,0,incomingData.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is undoubtedly that you are ignoring `incomingLength` after calling the `read()` method. Whatever else you're doing in this loop should only use `incomingData` from index `[0]` to index `[incomingLength-1],` and the loop should also break if `incomingLength < 0.`

A more conventional way to write it would be

```
while ((incomingLength = is.read(incomingData)) > 0)
{
    // ...
}
```

The different behaviour you are observing will be that with a new buffer every loop iteration you get trailing nulls instead of trailing garbage left over from the previous iteration.